# How to (auto)match the value of the container width to a custom fields value

Tags: containers, column-width

I've tried it a million different ways by now, and I'm completely losing my sanity.

I'm actually trying to create a progress bar (it isn't yet coded in the website). The value of the progress should be fetched from an other field, that was created with ACF.

I've tried to refer in the style and most recently I've been trying to refer in the div class

```
<html> 

<head> 
    <style> 
        p { 
            font-size: 20px; 
        } 

        .container { 
            background-color: rgb(238, 150, 165, 0.5); 
            width: 100%; 
            border-radius: 50px; 
        } 

        .skill { 
            background-color: rgb(238, 150, 165); 
            padding: 1%; 
            font-size: 20px; 
            border-radius: 50px; 
        } 
        
    </style> 
</head> 

<body> 
     
    <div class="container">         
        <div class= "skill"; width= "w-post-elm post_custom_field us_custom_5220e5b7 type_text %_sold color_link_inherit"></div>
    </div> 
</body> 



</html>
```